# Pivot longer - extract part of column name

Tags: r, pivot

I want to pivot to longer. Every column name that I wish to pivot has the same beginning; 'e_mort', so could be ignored, but I would ideally like to retain at the start of the new column names. The end of each column name is variable but always of the format of a variable length character and/or numeric string e.g. 'num' or '100k' either on its own or followed by an underscore and another character string (no numerics) e.g. 'num_lo' or '100k_lo'. The information I wish to extract and pivot is the central section of the column name, which will always be 'exc_tbhiv' or 'tbhiv'.

The dataset looks like this:

```
year <- c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002)

location <- rep(c("global","SA"), 3)

e_mort_exc_tbhiv_num <- c(1698959, 26000, 1693829, 27000, 1687579, 29000)

e_mort_exc_tbhiv_num_lo <- c(1600000, 25000, 1600000, 26000, 1600000, 28000)

e_mort_tbhiv_num <- c(674398, 116000, 652384, 144000, 616975, 136000)

e_mort_tbhiv_num_lo <- c(535000, 65000, 517000, 79000, 486000, 75000)

data <- tibble(year,location,
               e_mort_exc_tbhiv_num,
               e_mort_exc_tbhiv_num_lo,
               e_mort_tbhiv_num,
               e_mort_tbhiv_num_lo)

data
```

And the desired output is:

```
A tibble: 12 x 5
    year location group     e_mort_num e_mort_num_lo
   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>         <dbl>
 1  2000 global   exc_tbhiv    1698959       1600000
 2  2000 global   tbhiv         674398        535000
 3  2000 SA       exc_tbhiv      26000         25000
 4  2000 SA       tbhiv         116000         65000
 5  2001 global   exc_tbhiv    1693829       1600000
 6  2001 global   tbhiv         652384        517000
 7  2001 SA       exc_tbhiv      27000         26000
 8  2001 SA       tbhiv         144000         79000
 9  2002 global   exc_tbhiv    1687579       1600000
10  2002 global   tbhiv         616975        486000
11  2002 SA       exc_tbhiv      29000         28000
12  2002 SA       tbhiv         136000         75000
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Another option with a single `pivot_longer` call:

```r
pivot_longer(data, c(-year, -location), 
             names_pattern = "e_mort_(.*)_(num.*)", 
             names_to = c("group", ".value"))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#>     year location group         num  num_lo
#>    <dbl> <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1  2000 global   exc_tbhiv 1698959 1600000
#>  2  2000 global   tbhiv      674398  535000
#>  3  2000 SA       exc_tbhiv   26000   25000
#>  4  2000 SA       tbhiv      116000   65000
#>  5  2001 global   exc_tbhiv 1693829 1600000
#>  6  2001 global   tbhiv      652384  517000
#>  7  2001 SA       exc_tbhiv   27000   26000
#>  8  2001 SA       tbhiv      144000   79000
#>  9  2002 global   exc_tbhiv 1687579 1600000
#> 10  2002 global   tbhiv      616975  486000
#> 11  2002 SA       exc_tbhiv   29000   28000
#> 12  2002 SA       tbhiv      136000   75000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe should have been clearer in my question, this works for the example above, but in the actual dataset  the end of each column name is variable, not always containing 'num', but always of the format of a variable length character and/or numeric string e.g. 'num' or '100k' either on its own or followed by an underscore and another character string (no numerics) e.g. 'num_lo' or '100k_lo'.

Answer (score 1):

We could rename the columns by rearranging the substring and then use `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  rename_with(~ 
   str_replace(.x, "^(e_mort)_(.*)_((num|\\d+k)(_.*)?)", "\\1_\\3:\\2"),
      contains("_")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(year, location),
    names_to = c(".value", "group"), names_sep = ":")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 5
    year location group     e_mort_num e_mort_num_lo
   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>         <dbl>
 1  2000 global   exc_tbhiv    1698959       1600000
 2  2000 global   tbhiv         674398        535000
 3  2000 SA       exc_tbhiv      26000         25000
 4  2000 SA       tbhiv         116000         65000
 5  2001 global   exc_tbhiv    1693829       1600000
 6  2001 global   tbhiv         652384        517000
 7  2001 SA       exc_tbhiv      27000         26000
 8  2001 SA       tbhiv         144000         79000
 9  2002 global   exc_tbhiv    1687579       1600000
10  2002 global   tbhiv         616975        486000
11  2002 SA       exc_tbhiv      29000         28000
12  2002 SA       tbhiv         136000         75000
```